# Make every word in a string into classes

Tags: php, arrays, class

I am trying to create an CMS-system where I can add photos to my website, and for the photo-part, I want to have the ability to enter which programs I had used to create that photo.

I should be possible to add more than one program.

---

Right now I am saving the programs in the database like this:

**In the programs-row:**

> photoshop illistrator indesign

Then at my website, it could be nice if the icons/logos of the used programs, could show up next to the photo.

So my question is how to do create a new div, what a new class, based on the words from the programs-row?

**Fx:**

> *photoshop illustrator indesign*

**Becomes to:**

```
<div class="photoshop"></div>
<div class="illustrator"></div>
<div class="indesign"></div>
```

Hope you guys can help me with this problem :)

Thanks ;)

Comment: We will be able to provide useful answers when you show us your code and explain which part failed to perform as expected.

Comment: If you are at the point where you are legitimately trying to create a CMS then surely you know about basic string manipulation functions and loops?

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Grab the `photoshop illustrator indesign` from the database. Store each element in a string `$array[]` by using `substr`. Use a `foreach` (and perhaps a switch statement) to compare to all possible programs. If you have a match, `echo` out a new div with the current index of `$array[]` as the CSS class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the explode function and a foreach loop to perform the string manipulation.

```
$programs = explode(" ", $data);
foreach($programs as $value) {
    //Echo out the html - $value contains the program name
}
```

I leave it to you to figure out how to format the program name with the HTML that you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
$fx  = "photoshop illistrator indesign";
$words = explode(" ", $fx);
array_walk($words, function(&$n) { 
  echo '<div class="'.$n.'"></div>';
});
```

Comment: Isn't `array_walk()` a bit overkill for iterating over a simple array?

Comment: good question, no idea. All i know is that the anonymous function will only work with php5.3+